# Developer notices, warnings, message

Tags: developer-log

I constantly am getting the following messages in the developer logs:

```
Deprecated function decode_date() called in system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 10. Deprecated since 2.6. Use Localize::format_date instead.
```

I tried Googling or search the forums/internets/stackexchange for answer on what exactly the message is trying to tell me, but I have no idea.

Site is running EE 2.6.1. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An add-on you are using is called a deprecated function - which means that the function still works, but it has been superseded by a different function, and EllisLab wants developers to start using the new one. (This can be a pain for devs, since most want to support older versions of EE as well, which won't have the new function, so compatibility workarounds are required.)

It's nothing to worry about - eventually the developer will update the code (presumably before the deprecated function is removed). You can safely ignore the message.

Comment: Actually, it looks more like there's some PHP in a template that uses `Localize::decode_date()`, as the message mentions eval()'d code.

Comment: Nice catch @Low!

Comment: Thank you for helping. Just found there are a lot of templates with php that have that code. We will update the templates to fix this. Thanks @Low :-) and Derek of course!